# Android Java, Can call startForegroundService in MainActivity but not in another class/activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

i need your help to understand my error, i have a java script where i call a startForegroundService but nothing work if i dont do this in the Main activity

When a try use startForegroundService in my MainActivity everything is good, but for my projet i cant use this activity.

This code works

```
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
        startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

This code dont works.

```
package com.exemple.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Bridge {
    public static Activity unityActivity;
    public static void receiveUnityActivity(Activity tActivity){
        unityActivity = tActivity;

    }

    public static void Start(){
        unityActivity.startForegroundService(new Intent(unityActivity, ForegroundService.class));

    }
```

I call the start method with a c# script from unity. the c# script is good, i have tried call another  method and all works if i dont call a service.

I have check my manifest file and all service and permission is good.

So, where am I wrong?

Edit: I call receiveUnityService with a c# script from Unity3D

**c#**

```
AndroidJavaClass unityClass;
AndroidJavaObject unityActivity;
AndroidJavaClass customClass;

void Start()
{
    sendActivityReference("com.example.test.Bridge");

   startService();
}

void sendActivityReference(string packageName)
{
    unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    customClass = new AndroidJavaClass(packageName);
    customClass.CallStatic("receiveUnityActivity", unityActivity);
}

void startService()
{
    customClass.CallStatic("Start");
}
```

Comment: I call receiveUnityActivity() with a c# script from unity. The target service is the same in 2 code. I just forget the modify the name for the question. The first one is create with android studio the second is use like a plugin for unity3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally find the soluce. When you create a plugin for unity, you need two manifest file with the same permission. So you need one for unity and another one in the plugin when you build them.

But for now, i dont really understant why the unity manifest file need to be duplicate like this.

thanks for your help :D